# Using c library in swift project

Tags: c, swift3

I need to use this c library in swift code https://github.com/jmcnamara/libxlsxwriter
I go through the steps in https://kvurd.com/blog/building-libxlsxwriter-for-ios/ after creating the static library it builds successfuly but when adding to my project alwayes ther was error cannot found library.a file 
Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 3):

Cocoapods can help you.

`pod 'libxlsxwriter'` in your Podfile, then `pod install`

Then `import xlsxwriter` in any swift file you want to write `.xlsx` file.

That's all.